# Unity wait for WWW to finish without coroutine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to fetch some data from an API. I am using WWW class of the unity. How can I wait www class to finish without coroutine? I need to do without Coroutine because my dataManager class is not extending mono behaviour, and It is not attached to a game object, so I can not use coroutine. Any other methods that I can use ?

Comment: You must use the `WWW` API in a coroutine function. Wiating also requires coroutine. The duplicate shows you how to use coroutine in non `MonoBehaviour` class.

Comment: Yeah, thank you it helped me a lot :) And sorry for now researching properly.. I can not find this question before

Comment: No problem at-all